# Extract year from current_date

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I am working with postgresql and I have a question

How do i extract the year from my current_date. I know how to extract day, month or year from a given date (for example: 2020-10-29).
But I need to write a query, that gives certain informations between the beginning of the year and the end of the year.
Is there a way to extract the year from my current_date and then to use this as a
--select information between start extracted year from current_date and end extracted year from current_date.

Thanks in advance and stay healthy guys!

Comment: `extract(year from current_date)`

Comment: Please tell us what is your database ? Postgresql or Mysql ? Also, have you tried anything ?

Comment: extract(year from current_date) doesnt work.

Comment: working with postgresql on valentina studio

Comment: Please show us some data example of what you are trying to do ?

Comment: the task is to find out, who, in a company, has its 25 anniversary in 2020 or in 2021 or in 2022.... It has to be an 'automatic' query so i dont have to update it everytime im asking for the information.

Comment: Hi @skimmy So what kind of data do you receive ? Do you receive/send a year like 2020 and then you have to find our who of the employees have their 25th anniversary in that year ? Also, please note that this is not a good way to ask a question. You always have to provide a example data and expected result from that data in your question...

Comment: @VBoka im totaly new to all of this :D i am sorry.

Comment: @skimmy . . . To me, your question is very vague and broad.  I would suggest that you ask a *new8 question and provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation for what you want to calculate.

Comment: Hi @skimmy click edit at the bottom of your question and add some example data...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you don't want to compare the year only. Instead, you would typically truncate the current date to the beginning of the year.

In Postgres:

```
where mydate >= date_trunc('year', current_date)
```

If you want a check on the upper bound as well:

```
where mydate >= date_trunc('year', current_date)
  and mydate <  date_trunc('year', current_date) + interval '1 year'
```

If, for some other reason, you need to extract the current year, then use `extract()`:

```
extract(year from current_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example I have simulated the date you are sending/receiving as a c_d.
Also, your data is in the table called "test" in this example...

```
WITH curr_date AS (
    SELECT to_date('2020-05-29', 'yyy-mm-dd') c_d
)
select *
from test
where EXTRACT(YEAR FROM my_date) = (select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c_d) from curr_date);
```

Here is a demo:

> > [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=49f5434868d5ab7f6509e62b840106be)